# Error to install mongodb in lumen

Tags: mongodb, laravel, ubuntu-14.04, laravel-5, lumen

I use Lumen micro framework on ubuntu 14.4,when i want to install monogodb packege form [this link](https://github.com/jenssegers/laravel-mongodb) i got a error like below:

```
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

Problem 1
- jenssegers/mongodb v3.0.0 requires mongodb/mongodb ^1.0.0 -> satisfiable by mongodb/mongodb[1.0.0, 1.0.1].
- jenssegers/mongodb v3.0.1 requires mongodb/mongodb ^1.0.0 -> satisfiable by mongodb/mongodb[1.0.0, 1.0.1].
- jenssegers/mongodb v3.0.2 requires mongodb/mongodb ^1.0.0 -> satisfiable by mongodb/mongodb[1.0.0, 1.0.1].
- mongodb/mongodb 1.0.1 requires ext-mongodb ^1.1.0 -> the requested PHP extension mongodb is missing from your system.
- mongodb/mongodb 1.0.0 requires ext-mongodb ^1.1.0 -> the requested PHP extension mongodb is missing from your system.
- Installation request for jenssegers/mongodb ^3.0 -> satisfiable by jenssegers/mongodb[v3.0.0, v3.0.1, v3.0.2].

To enable extensions, verify that they are enabled in those .ini files:
- /etc/php5/cli/php.ini
- /etc/php5/cli/conf.d/05-opcache.ini
- /etc/php5/cli/conf.d/10-pdo.ini
- /etc/php5/cli/conf.d/20-curl.ini
- /etc/php5/cli/conf.d/20-gd.ini
- /etc/php5/cli/conf.d/20-json.ini
- /etc/php5/cli/conf.d/20-mcrypt.ini
- /etc/php5/cli/conf.d/20-mysql.ini
- /etc/php5/cli/conf.d/20-mysqli.ini
- /etc/php5/cli/conf.d/20-pdo_mysql.ini
- /etc/php5/cli/conf.d/20-readline.ini
- /etc/php5/cli/conf.d/mongo.ini
You can also run `php --ini` inside terminal to see which files are used by PHP in CLI mode.

Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json to its original content.
```

How can i fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have the php mongodb driver/extension installed

use this

```
sudo apt-get install php5-mongo
```

if you are on php 5

Comment: i got error `E: Package 'php5-mongo' has no installation candidate`

Comment: complete error is `Package php5-mongo is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'php5-mongo' has no installation candidate
`

Comment: please help me friends

Comment: sorry have been busy. go to the terminal and type **php -m** and let see if you have mongo among the installed modules

Comment: which version of php are you using.

Comment: i use `PHP 5.5.9-1ubuntu4.14 (cli) (built: Oct 28 2015 01:34:46) 
`

Comment: i use [this link](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-linux-apache-mysql-php-lamp-stack-on-ubuntu) to install php

Comment: use this link to build the connection between php and mongo. check the step 4 http://tecadmin.net/setup-mongodb-php5-apache2-ubuntu/ Dont forget to restart your server after the installation

Comment: i use `sudo pecl install mongo` i got error `pecl/mongo is already installed and is the same as the released version 1.6.12
install failed
`

Comment: also i runnig `sudo echo "extension=mongo.so" >> /etc/php5/apache2/php.ini` and `sudo service apache2 restart` but i got same error to install lumen mongodb package

Comment: Do **php --ini** to check the php.ini you are using

Comment: `Configuration File (php.ini) Path: /etc/php5/cli
Loaded Configuration File:         /etc/php5/cli/php.ini
Scan for additional .ini files in: /etc/php5/cli/conf.d
Additional .ini files parsed:      /etc/php5/cli/conf.d/05-opcache.ini,
/etc/php5/cli/conf.d/10-pdo.ini,
/etc/php5/cli/conf.d/20-curl.ini,
/etc/php5/cli/conf.d/20-gd.ini,
/etc/php5/cli/conf.d/20-json.ini,
/etc/php5/cli/conf.d/20-mcrypt.ini,
/etc/php5/cli/conf.d/20-mysql.ini,
/etc/php5/cli/conf.d/20-mysqli.ini,
/etc/php5/cli/conf.d/20-pdo_mysql.ini,
/etc/php5/cli/conf.d/20-readline.ini`

Comment: Check inside the loaded configuration *php.ini* to see if mongo is enabled or you will see the line extension=mongo.so

Comment: i got same error :( when run `sudo echo "extension=mongo.so" >> /etc/php5/cli/php.ini` error is `PHP Warning:  Module 'mongo' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
`

Comment: Can you restart your server(if its not a production server) and try the package again.

Comment: but it's not a server

Answer (score 0):

When i run `php -m`  i got :

```
amirali@amirali-U30J:~$ php -m
PHP Warning:  Module 'mongo' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
[PHP Modules]
bcmath
bz2
calendar
Core
ctype
curl
date
dba
dom
ereg
exif
fileinfo
filter
ftp
gd
gettext
hash
iconv
json
libxml
mbstring
mcrypt
mhash
mongo
mysql
mysqli
openssl
pcntl
pcre
PDO
pdo_mysql
Phar
posix
readline
Reflection
session
shmop
SimpleXML
soap
sockets
SPL
standard
sysvmsg
sysvsem
sysvshm
tokenizer
wddx
xml
xmlreader
xmlwriter
Zend OPcache
zip
zlib

[Zend Modules]
Zend OPcache
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [pecl](https://pecl.php.net/) instead.

```
pecl install mongodb
```

See [here](https://pecl.php.net/package/mongodb).